# MonoTouch dialog - MessageElement

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a MT Dialog control that I have added the following to it.

```
Root
---->Section
--------->MessageElement
--------->MessageElement
--------->MessageElement
--------->MessageElement etc.
```

The problem is how do I add fields under the MessageElement so that when the user clicks on the MessageElement I get the form fields.

```
var root = new RootElement("Jobs");
var section = new Section();
root.Add(section);
foreach(var job in jobItems) {

    var m = new MessageElement();
    m.Body=job.dbInstructions;
    m.Caption = "My Caption";
    m.Date = DateTime.Parse(job.dbDueDate);
    m.Subject=job.dbSiteVenueName;
    m.Sender=job.dbServiceGroup;
    section.Add(m);
}
var jobsDialog = new DialogViewController(root);
..
```